# How to capture note screenshot from web page using typescript

Tags: typescript, web-scraping, automation, typescript-generics, web-scripting

I wanted to write code in typesript to capture image from web page
Like all browser have option in inspect element -> select element -> right click -> capture note screenshot
As show in screenshot: [image: capture note screenshot]

Code in typesript which will accept page url and capture the image.

Comment: what automation framework are you using? selenium, cypress, testcafe, playwrite there are many out there? some idea on it will help in answering.

Comment: Plain typescript code no framework.